# Change the color of selected Tab, of TabMenu PRIMENG - style

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, primeng, tabmenu

I'm using primeng component tab menu. 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tabmenu
I can't find a way to change the color of the selected TAB, to a different one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer. Just to keep in mind you should add `:host ::ng-deep` before your css class to override any style

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem.ui-state-active {
    background-color: #d90096; //<Replace your custom color>
    border: 1px solid #d600d9;
}
```

Hopefully it will save your time.

Comment: You're totally right! That's why i could only make it work if i add it on app level SCSS. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
    body .ui-tabview.ui-tabview-top .ui-tabview-nav li.ui-state-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Source:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=58188

Comment: Not working... I'm watching the link you send, try to solve it. thanks !

Comment: Do you know what encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None is?

Comment: @jcmendes98 Please create and link to a seperate question, so that users can answer this.

Answer (score 1):

You can override its default CSS selector like below:

```
body .ui-tabmenu .ui-tabmenu-nav .ui-tabmenuitem.ui-state-active {
    background-color: #d90096; //<Replace your custom color>
    border: 1px solid #d600d9;
}
```

Another way to user upper tag binding with `<li>`

```
li.ui-tabmenuitem.ui-state-default.ui-state-active {
   background-color: #d90096; //<Replace your custom color>
   border: 1px solid #d600d9;
}
```

You need to change both **background-color** & **border** so it will apply.

You can inspect from demo UI and update lively over there, for more info please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Hope this will helps!

Comment: I have added another way to override class. check my update answer

Comment: I add it to my scss and it does nothing, even with !important. Don't know why... Tried it a billion times already. Thanks for your time. I must have a stupid error somewhere.

Comment: I DID IT! Don't know why but the only way i could make the scss work was to paste it on the app.scss instead of the page scss. Working in an Ionic project. It must be a bug...

Comment: I would rather have the css styling in a theme rather than styling it an app level

Comment: it work on page level if you add :host ::ng-deep as Ragavan Rajan said. Otherwise i will only work on app level scss.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. `ui-tabview-selected` will change the colour of the selected tab.
`ui-state-default.ui-state-active` background should be added to give colour to the remaining area.

```
.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav li.ui-tabview-selected a {  
    background-color: rgb(57, 235, 175);
}

.ui-tabview .ui-tabview-nav li.ui-state-default.ui-state-active {
    background: #f55555;
}
```

Try this link
[Styling PrimeNG p-tabView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430376/styling-primeng-p-tabview), I got some codes and modified them on my code.

You can have a better understanding of what `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` by referring to this line.

[Diff between ViewEncapsulation.Native, ViewEncapsulation.None and ViewEncapsulation.Emulated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651993/diff-between-viewencapsulation-native-viewencapsulation-none-and-viewencapsulat)

Comment: Parts of your answer are link-only, which is considered not an answer on StackOverflow. Other parts are answering, but sadly in code-only. Which is seen as an answer, but not a good one. Also quoting questions which OP has asked in comments puts your post at risk of being mistaken (by lazy readers) for a question instead of an answet. Please make the asker to create separate questions and answer there. Note that questions which contain several questions are usually flagged and closed as lacking focus. Not your fault, but you might end up on the suffering end here....

Comment: You can comment on this, your own post, to ask OP to edit their question and create new ones. But I also did that in a direct comment for you already.

Comment: "code-only" means your answer only contains code, but no explanation how it works and why it helps to solve the problem described in the question. It gives the false impression that StackOverflow is a free code writing service. So please [edit] and add explanation.